# How to use `build_runner` at runtime?

Tags: dart, build, code-generation

I want to generate code from dart files especially from dart packages at runtime.

I have been using `build_runner` as a dev_dependency to parse and generate code, which is really awesome! But the problem that I don't know how to use it as a normal dependency so I can use in my application.

Also I found that `build_runner` uses `analyzer` as a core, but didn't find good documentation about them.

So, how can I use `build_runner` as a normal dependency to parse and generate code at runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform actions that the `build_runner run` CLI command does with the [`run`](https://pub.dev/documentation/build_runner/latest/build_runner/run.html) function exposed programatically.

For lower-level access to build logic that may be more suited to programatic usage, the [APIs provided by `package:build`](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/build/README.md) may be more useful. Alternatively, the actual code generation packages may expose their own APIs for code generation.